# Broadcast Receiver in Service not receiving Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-broadcastreceiver

I know there are a bunch of questions related to this topic but nothing seems to work for me.

I have a service which receives broadcasts from multiple activities and I am differentiating them using different actions for each broadcast received.

Here is my code

MyService.java // This is service class

```
private BroadcastReceiver SleepTimeReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG,"SleepTimeReceiver onReceive is called");
        if (intent.getAction().equals("sleepTimeFinished")) {
            Log.d(TAG,"intents are matching");
        }
    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.d(TAG,"onCreate is called");
    .
    .
    registerReceiver(SleepTimeReceiver,new IntentFilter("sleepTimeFinished"));
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.d(TAG, "on destroy is called");
    unregisterReceiver(SleepTimeReceiver);
}
```

MyActivity.java // This is activity class

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(TAG,"About to send broadcast");
    Intent sleepTimeFinishedIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
    sleepTimeFinishedIntent.setAction("sleepTimeFinished");
    sendBroadcast(sleepTimeFinishedIntent);
    Log.d(TAG,"broadcast has been sent");
}
```

I have also tried to add the receiver in the manifest file but to no avail. In the logcat, I can see the logs from all methods except for the onReceive method of the receiver. Can someone help me on this. This simple issue has been bugging me for hours now.

Comment: what do you need thay `BroadcastReceiver` for? why dont you use `startService` to "talk" to your `Service`?

Comment: I am actually using the service to play music. This activity lets the service know when to stop playing the music based on user choice.

Comment: so you dont need it at all: either `bindService` from your activity (recommended) or talk to your service via `startService` calls (not recommended)

Comment: Hey thanks for your time. I have created a method in service class where I have put the code to stop the music and am calling that method whenever necessary.

Comment: I am able to solve the issue for now but still could not figure out why that broadcast intent was not being received.

Comment: because you were sending a broadcast before `registerReceiver` was called?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115020/discussion-between-nikhil-and-pskink).

Comment: @Nikhil Have you given my solution a try?

Comment: @REG1 Yes I did but it wasn't working.

Comment: @Nikhil Do you recall the error?

Comment: @REG1 There was no error as such. Just that the broadcast was not being received by the receiver, which I could tell by looking at the logcat.

Comment: @Nikhil Ok, that's odd...looks like the issues lie beyond this code.

Answer (score 0):

Did you start Service? I don't see starting in onCreate, and there you send broadcast - maybe receiver isn't yet registered?

Comment: Yes I have already started service using a different activity. That is not an issue.

Comment: Your broadcast don't get Intent, because you specify MyService as Component for it in `new Intent(this, MyService.class);`. Try with empty constructor and Intent goes to your receiver.

Comment: I tried the method you suggested but it is still not receiving the intent.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you should be using the [LocalBroadcastManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) as you are only handling broadcasts sent from within your own application.

So within `onCreate()` of `MyService.java` register your `BroadcastReceiver` like this:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(sleepTimeReceiver, new IntentFilter("sleepTimeFinished"));
```

Then from `onCreate()` of `MyActivity.java` send your broadcast like this:

```
Intent sleepTimeFinishedIntent = new Intent("sleepTimeFinished");
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(sleepTimeFinishedIntent);
```

In `onDestroy()` of MyService.java unregister your local broadcast receiver like this:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(sleepTimeReceiver);
```

As you may have noticed I also changed the name of your broadcast receiver to start with a lower case letter, simply for consistency.
So it's `sleepTimeReceiver` and not `SleepTimeReceiver`.